# How to add sequentials in a numbar using formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a Formula to use in my table, that will get me the following result

Please check this image

[image]

In B2 for example it is 1+2+3+4+5
In B3 As Another example it is 1+2+3+4+5+6
etc...
thank you

Comment: Please note OP has already posted the same query in Facebook and i have already provided the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [simple math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223907/what-is-n-n-1-n-2-cdots-1-called/3223908):

```
=A2*(A2+1)/2
```

[image]

Comment: pfft, I was being too literal.  I knew this too.

Comment: BigBen Sir, its nice, but OP posted the query in FB, in a different way, and then again edited with the proper requirement as he had shown here.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - good to know, but I can't really do a lot about that. I only frequent SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Formula used in cell B2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&$A2)))
```

[image: SOLUTION]